# What is a good microcontroller for PWM signal generation?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

I want to build a Pulse Width Modulation board, something that would allow me to send different PWM signals to the devices connected to the board.
My main criteria - is being able to send at least 4 different PWM signals at the same time (e.g. with different frequency)

I need a microcontroller or chip which is not too hard to work with, preferably supports gcc and can handle PWM.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Most microcontrollers support multiple PWM signals. There's nothing special about them. Unfortunately, that means this is just a shopping question and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: PWM hardware is available in (nearly) all but the most basic microcontrollers in (nearly) all microcontroller families. Most microcontroller families (except the <32 bit PICs and 8051s(?)) are supported by GCC. Hence your choice is almost unlimited :)

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for such an 'obvious' question, I am very new to the subject, glad there are plenty solutions out there. I am currently looking into the AVR chips.
*[I flagged the post to be closed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [AVR with 4 or more timers](http://www.atmel.com/v2PFResults.aspx#%28actives:!%288238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8392,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8248,8264,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278%29,data:%28area:%27%27,category:%2734864[33180]%27,pm:!%28%28i:8238,v:!%281,16%29%29,%28i:8394,v:!%280,17%29%29,%28i:8362,v:!%282,28%29%29,%28i:8282,v:!%285%29%29,%28i:8431,v:!%281,33%29%29,%28i:8300,v:!%281,8%29%29,%28i:8358,v:!%282,68%29%29,%28i:8392,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8378,v:!n%29,%28i:8445,v:!%281,4,5,6,7,9%29%29,%28i:8236,v:!%280,24%29%29,%28i:8449,v:!%284,10%29%29,%28i:8474,v:!%280%29%29,%28i:8248,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8264,v:!%281,5%29%29,%28i:8447,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8256,v:!%281,2,4%29%29,%28i:8254,v:!%283,16%29%29,%28i:8286,v:!%280,3%29%29,%28i:8462,v:!%280,8%29%29,%28i:8429,v:!%281,10%29%29,%28i:8458,v:!%280,4%29%29,%28i:8466,v:!%281,2,4%29%29,%28i:8400,v:!%280,20%29%29,%28i:8302,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8278,v:!%280,1,2%29%29%29,view:list%29,sc:1%29) will support that many frequencies, and GCC has good *vendor* support and the architecture is almost drop-dead easy to use.